# Is "had come" correct in my response about why I was late, or should I have chosen a different tense?

Tags: past-perfect

Please help me with the version of my answer.

Is it OK if I use *had come* in my sentence?

> My colleague: Why are you so late? We have been waiting for you.
>   Me: Actually my boss **had come** to my desk to ask about my assignment and it took me 10 min to explain him, hence I was late.

According to me using *had come* gives idea about first completed action of coming to my desk and then second action of explanation.

Comment: No, you have to use "*my boss came to my desk*" here.

Comment: You have used **had come** correctly.   Simple past **came** would also be acceptable.  However **explain**  is not used correctly.  We **explain** something **to** someone.  It took you ten minutes to explain it to him.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with @Teleporting Goat - "came" is correct here. "Had come" is the past *perfect* tense, which is used to describe something that happened *before another action*. It would be correct to say, "My boss came to my desk, but my coworker had come already." This means that your coworker was there before your boss. The reason why I think "had come" is incorrect is because you aren't saying that something else happened *before* your boss came to your desk.

> According to me using Had come gives idea about fist completed action of coming to my desk and then second action of explanation.

Close, but "had come" doesn't imply this - at least, not in the original sentence. Your original sentence (with the correct verb) already makes that implication, actually; you don't need "had come" to convey that.

> "My boss came to my desk and it took me 10 minutes to explain X to him."

"And" loosely implies a sequence, especially because coming to your desk seems like something that would happen before the explanation.

Some other examples:

> "The player kicked the ball and scored a goal."
>
> "I buckled my seatbelt and turned on the ignition."

Both of those sentences are technically correct regardless of the order in which the actions happened. But the implication is that the two actions happened in sequence.